# Can't connect to embedded Derby database in IntelliJ IDEA because database is in use

Tags: java, intellij-idea, derby, embedded-database

I'm working on an app that uses embedded database (Derby). My IDE is IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3. I tried creating the database in the IDE:

> Database > New > Data Source > Derby > Embedded

The database is created in Program Files, in IDEA's folder. However, I can't access it with this:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:databaseName;create=true");
```

When I try to connect to the database (using the line above) it creates a new database in the project folder.

Is there a way to easily connect to the database from the app and manage it in IDEA's data source manager?

Comment: Are you asking how to specify the filesystem location of the database? If so, you do that by specifying the full path name in your JDBC connection URL. The "jdbc:derby:databaseName" is using a relative path name ("databaseName"); you could try "jdbc:derby:/path/to/my/databaseName".

Comment: Thanks for reaction, but it seems I've solved it. I have tried millions of combinations, including the one you've suggested, but I've overlooked one serious mistake. JVM refused to connect to the database, because the IDE was using it. I just have to disconnect for the time I'm running the app...